# How to let Username column in the GridView to be opened in the Outlook?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I developed a web-based training matrix that shows the training record for each employee in each division in my department in the company. The matrix will show many columns such as the employee name, username, job title... etc. what I want now is to make the username for each employee to be clickable which means when the admin clicks on it, the outlook will be opened with his email and the admin will be able to send him a message. In my company, this is possible because each employee email is mainly as: username@companyName.com so how to do that?

By the way, the username of the employee will be retrieved from the database using a storedprocedure. The user column is the 4th column in the GridView.

what I did is the following:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
        {
            ///Add mailto to the Username column
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "<a href='mailto:'" + e.Row.Cells[3].Text + "@aramco.com?Subject=About%20Your%20Safety%20Training%20Record" +" />" + e.Row.Cells[3].Text + "</a>";
            }
     }
```

I could be able to let the username of each employee to be clickable, but I could not be able to put his email in the Outlook what it is opened, **so how to do that?**

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens when you click the link now?

Answer (score 0):

You can create **Hyperlink** like below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            OnRowDataBound="grd_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="click Me" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>



protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink btn1 = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("btn1");
        btn1.NavigateUrl = "mailto:abc@yahoo.com";
    }
}
```

---

Or like below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     OnRowDataBound="grd_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("EMail", "mailto:{0}") %>' Text="Hi"></asp:HyperLink>
               </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```